# Почему вместо id записи Wordpress возвращается значение NULL?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Почему вместо id записи Wordpress возвращается значение NULL?

Код:

```
function create_posttype_movies() {
    register_post_type( 'movies',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_movies' );

function add_noindex_for_movies() {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    var_dump($id); //NULL
    print_r($id);
    $type = get_post_type($id);
    var_dump($type);
    if ($type == 'movies') {
        add_action('wp_head', 'wp_no_robots');
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'add_noindex_for_movies' );
```

Как еще можно получить id custom post type?

Как видно на скриншоте ниже, id страницы 207

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что во время события `init` главный цикл WordPress ещё не инициализирован, глобальная переменная `$post` не существует. Сделайте вызов позже:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'add_noindex_for_movies' );
```

Во время события `wp` цикл уже установлен.

Можно сделать даже так:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_noindex_for_movies', 0 );
```

и ваша функция `add_noindex_for_movies` стартует раньше всех остальных в `wp_head` и успеет добавить в хуки `wp_head` функцию `wp_no_robots` с приоритетом по умолчанию 10. Чем ниже значение приоритета, тем раньше стартует функция хука.

Подробнее о порядке загрузки WordPress можно прочитать [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).